# Storing and processing too many images with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-recognition

I am working on a Image detection problem in opencv for which I need to save many images.

These images are required to be accessed frequently so I wanted to store these images in IPL image format . All these images are grayscale images .

What I wanted to ask is what is the best method to handle all these Images ? 
Should I store them in a database or a file system ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I had a related question a while ago, may be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714358/smart-caching-of-expensive-objects-in-python

Comment: Friend , What I am asking is somewhat similar. But suppose I have 1 million images and  I need to compare my image with all those images for a similarity then I cannot create a dictionary (memory reasons ) . I need to use a database or file system .

Comment: Since you can't fit all the images in memory, you can read the images from files first and then save them to disk using [FileStorage](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html). Then you can load a batch of images from an  xml file to memory for processing.

Comment: Thanks ! I will look into this and get back to you !

Comment: @HammadHaleem , i am stuck on a similar problem .. are you able to get a solution for this ?

Comment: Depending on the specifics of your application, it may be a better idea to compute a metric on the images and save that instead. For the example of similarity mentioned above, you could compute the mean and standard deviation of image intensity (not the best example, but you get the point) and use that to narrow down the search candidates. Either way, whether you use a database or a file system, the raw image data will have to be on the disk and computation speed will be limited by disk access first and database efficienty second.